# Pegar ID de usuário em um formulário

Tags: javascript, html

Vou desenvolver uma plataforma WEB, e no software em certo contexto há a possibilidade de um determinado usuário ver o perfil de outros usuários, ver suas informações públicas cadastradas e em formulário atrelado a cara perfil, mandar mensagens para quaisquer um dos da lista. Pretendo implementar o envio e recebimento das mensagens no FrontEnd mesmo. Tenho ideia de como pegar o texto digitado no campo para a mensagem, mas também queria pegar o ID do usuário que digitou no campo, para jogar essas informações para o perfil do usuário que recebe a mensagem, e a partir daí ele poderá ver a mensagem, e, utilizando o ID, foto e nome do remetente. Mas não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso, então me respondam aí, quem já tiver implementado algo do tipo, ou tem alguma lógica que me seria de grande valia. Desde já, grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você que fazer, pode tentar o seguinte:
Mesmo querendo fazer tudo no Front End, vai precisar de algum tipo de BackEnd para pelo menos persistir os dados, a não ser que queira salvar tudo em arquivo, o que te daria mais trabalho do que configurar um backend simples, além de salvar em arquivo não ser uma boa pratica. Com o backend definido, faça:

- Crie um sistema de login para cadastro (nome, foto, e-mail, etc ...)
- Apos o sistema de login
- Apos o usuário logar na sua aplicação, você terá disponível este usuário na seção
- Apenas associe essas informações da seção, no objeto da mensagem.

Uma dica simples pra fazer tudo isso é utilizar o Angular 2+ e o Firebase como backend pra salvar teus dados, se ainda não conhece, vale a pena dar uma olhada, com poucas linhas vai fazer a autenticação e obter os dados que deseja.

- [Exemplo de login com firebase e angular 2+](https://github.com/jonatansouza/angular4-firebase)

Obs: O backend é indispensável no seu cenário, [Como funciona aplicações web](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-funcionam-as-aplicacoes-web/25888).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica!